# Geodjango: How to Buffer From Point

Tags: python, django, filter, buffer, geodjango

I want to have a radius based distance search. To do this, I want to create a buffer around a point object in order to filter objects that are inside it.

Here is where I am at with it:

```
>>> lat = 37.7762179974
>>> lon = -122.411562492
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> pnt = Point(lat, lon)
>>> buf = pnt.buffer(0.0001)
```

But I am having problems filtering the `Thing` objects based on whether they are inside the buffer:

```
>>> z = Thing.objects.filter(pnt__intersects=buf)
```

(*I know that the above is incorrect, but I use it to elaborate what I am trying to do.*)

How can I create a buffer around the `Point` and then filter `Things` that are inside the `buffer`?

---

EDIT: `models.py`

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
```

How can I filter based on a point comprised of a combination of these two model fields? 
This cannot work obviously, because I do not have a `pnt` field in my model:

```
>>> pnt = Point(lat, lon)
>>> z = Thing.objects.filter(pnt__intersects=buf)
```

But how can I do something similar?

Comment: Hey, @NickB I posted a slightly late (only by 3 years) answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS has a method called [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) which can create a 2D, 3D or 4D point.

In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos/45633779#45633779) we saw that it is possible to create a custom database function from an existing PostGIS function:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

class MakePoint(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_MakePoint'
```

Now we can create a point by [`annotate()`ing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and apply the `intersects` on it:

```
z = Thing.objects.annotate(pnt=MakePoint('lat', 'lon'))
                 .filter(pnt__intersects=buf)
```

You can achieve the same effect by utilizing [`GeoFunc()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L88) and [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

z = Thing.objects.annotate(pnt=GeoFunc(
        F('lat'), F('lon'),
        function='ST_MakePoint'
    )).filter(pnt__intersects=buf)
```

---

*Note:* You could consider adding a `pnt` field in your `Thing` model and avoid the above.

Comment: GeoFunc needs a closing bracket. Edit queue is full.

Comment: @ZuLu good catch, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "buffer", but if you want a radius based distance search you might try using the... distance!

Here is an example with a kilometer metric:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

Thing.objects.filter(pnt__distance_lte=(pnt,D(km=distance)))
```

You should certainly have a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear, but I think you have missed my point (pun intended). I don't have a model field named `pnt`, only `lat` and `lon`, so I cannot filter based on `pnt`. I would just like to know a way to filter based on `lat + lon`. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: If there is no 'pnt' field in your model, '.filter(pnt__*)' has no sense to me. Since you are storing 'lat' and 'lon' as floats in your database, what's the point of using GeoDjango in the first place?

Comment: I was following the method [described in this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/geodjango/distance%2420search%2420geodjango%2420hekevintran/geodjango/butW7zJQhSw/4Os60LTdEywJ). Since it was written by the "lead developer of geodjango," I considered it a trustworthy source. However, I am not the authority on the topic and am willing to take additional feedback. I appreciate all of your comments up to this point!

Comment: Your reference post dates back to Django 1.2 and the situation described in it is quite different from yours. You shouldn't have a `lat` and `lon`float fields in your model, but one and only `PointField`.

Answer (score 0):

Update ... em 2023 django==4.2

```py
     from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

    In [1]: p = GEOSGeometry("POINT (-45.8872 -23.1791)") #

    In [2]: RAIOKM = 40

    In [3]: KM_GRAD_TAXA = 111.32

    In [4]: b = p.buffer(RAIOKM/KM_GRAD_TAXA, 16) # com um poly de 16 vertex

    In [5]: b.json
    Out[5]: '{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -45.527875530003591, -23.1791 ], [ -45.529605775539991, -23.214319956999482 ], [ -45.534779848938832, -23.24920072655987 ], [ -45.543347921044841, -23.283406387802536 ], [ -45.555227476639857, -23.316607521510988 ], [ -45.570304109109465, -23.348484382618036 ], [ -45.588432622241271, -23.378729979525549 ], [ -45.609438428543754, -23.407053030601379 ], [ -45.633119230619279, -23.433180769380719 ], [ -45.659246969398616, -23.456861571456244 ], [ -45.687570020474453, -23.477867377758727 ], [ -45.717815617381966, -23.49599589089053 ], [ -45.74969247848901, -23.511072523360145 ], [ -45.782893612197462, -23.522952078955157 ], [ -45.817099273440128, -23.531520151061166 ], [ -45.851980043000516, -23.536694224460003 ], [ -45.8872, -23.538424469996404 ], [ -45.922419956999484, -23.536694224460003 ], [ -45.957300726559872, -23.531520151061166 ], [ -45.991506387802538, -23.522952078955157 ], [ -46.02470752151099, -23.511072523360145 ], [ -46.056584382618034, -23.495995890890534 ], [ -46.086829979525547, -23.477867377758727 ], [ -46.115153030601384, -23.456861571456248 ], [ -46.141280769380721, -23.433180769380719 ], [ -46.164961571456246, -23.407053030601382 ], [ -46.185967377758729, -23.378729979525549 ], [ -46.204095890890535, -23.348484382618036 ], [ -46.219172523360143, -23.316607521510992 ], [ -46.231052078955159, -23.283406387802536 ], [ -46.239620151061168, -23.249200726559874 ], [ -46.244794224460009, -23.214319956999482 ], [ -46.246524469996409, -23.1791 ], [ -46.244794224460009, -23.143880043000514 ], [ -46.239620151061168, -23.108999273440126 ], [ -46.231052078955159, -23.07479361219746 ], [ -46.219172523360143, -23.041592478489008 ], [ -46.204095890890535, -23.009715617381961 ], [ -46.185967377758729, -22.979470020474448 ], [ -46.164961571456246, -22.951146969398618 ], [ -46.141280769380721, -22.925019230619277 ], [ -46.115153030601384, -22.901338428543752 ], [ -46.086829979525547, -22.880332622241269 ], [ -46.056584382618034, -22.862204109109467 ], [ -46.02470752151099, -22.847127476639852 ], [ -45.991506387802538, -22.835247921044839 ], [ -45.957300726559872, -22.826679848938831 ], [ -45.922419956999484, -22.821505775539993 ], [ -45.8872, -22.819775530003593 ], [ -45.851980043000516, -22.821505775539993 ], [ -45.817099273440128, -22.826679848938831 ], [ -45.782893612197462, -22.835247921044839 ], [ -45.74969247848901, -22.847127476639852 ], [ -45.717815617381966, -22.862204109109463 ], [ -45.687570020474453, -22.880332622241266 ], [ -45.659246969398623, -22.901338428543749 ], [ -45.633119230619279, -22.925019230619277 ], [ -45.609438428543754, -22.951146969398614 ], [ -45.588432622241271, -22.979470020474448 ], [ -45.570304109109465, -23.009715617381961 ], [ -45.555227476639857, -23.041592478489004 ], [ -45.543347921044841, -23.074793612197457 ], [ -45.534779848938832, -23.108999273440123 ], [ -45.529605775539991, -23.143880043000511 ], [ -45.527875530003591, -23.1791 ], [ -45.527875530003591, -23.1791 ] ] ] }'
```

... you are using Django, you may have PostGIS Extension

```sql
 SELECT jsonb_build_object(
       'type',     'FeatureCollection', 
       'features', jsonb_agg(features.feature) 
    ) 
    FROM ( 
       SELECT jsonb_build_object( 
          'type',       'Feature', 
          'id',         id, 
          'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(buffer)::jsonb, 
          'properties', to_jsonb(inputs) - 'id' - 'buffer' 
       ) AS feature 
       FROM ( 
          SELECT  
             *, ST_Buffer( 
                 geography( ST_Transform( ponto_geo, 4326 )), 10000 
            )::geometry as buffer 
          FROM tabela1 
          where ponto_geo is not null 
       ) inputs 
        ) features; 

    /*  
    tabela1 - table
    ponto_geo - field `ponto_geo public.geometry(point, 4326) NULL,`
    
    */
```

the query generates a perfect GeoJson compatible , but you can use the `ST_Buffer` direct in a query ;)