# Equivalent of PostGIS ST_MakeValid in Django GEOS

Tags: gis

Upon checking a polygon object's validity using `Objects.polygon.valid`, it thrown a `GEOS_NOTICE: Self-intersection` error.

I know this can be fixed by using the `ST_MakeValid` method of PostGIS.
I'm using Django 1.11 with GEOS support and can't find its equivalent in Django docs.

Is there any equivalent function for `ST_MakeValid` in Django?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Django version >= 1.10:**

Exists the database method: [`MakeValid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#makevalid)

**Django version < 1.10:**

You can create a custom database function by extending [`GeoFunc`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L93) class which by itself extends the [`Func()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) class:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

class MakeValid(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_MakeValid'
```

The `MakeValid(field_name)` applies the `ST_MakeValid` to the field with `field_name`.

---

**Usage:**

```
YourModel.objects.get(id=an_id).update(the_geom=MakeValid('the_geom'))
```

The following is an equivalent query using [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression to execute the update:

```
YourModel.objects.get(id=an_id)
                 .update(the_geom=GeoFunc(
                     F('the_geom'), 
                     function='ST_MakeValid'
                 ))
```

*Note:* `the_geom` represents your geometry field (point, polygon, etc.)

Comment: One more doubt in using this function: when I do `new_polygon_obj = MakeValid(<MultiPolygon object at 0x7fe4f5030120>)`, it doesn't return a new multi-polygon object. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually writing as you shown here? If that is the case you are using it wrong and you should use it as I suggest in my answer @ajaysingh

Comment: I can't do this `YourModel.objects.get(id=an_id).update(the_geom=MakeValid('the_geom'))` as I already have the object in my code. I just need to update the polygon object with something like `YourModel.polygon = MakeValid(YourModel.polygon)` and save it later. Why can't I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because Django does not work that way @ajaysingh. Try this: `YourModel.objects.get(id=an_id).update(polygon=MakeValid('polygon'))` and you should be able to update your polygon with the valid one! Careful of the names!!

Comment: Actually, I need to save/update my `YourModel` later. Can you please help me to extract geom object from `MakeValid(YourModel.polygon)` which I need?

Comment: @ajaysingh I do believe that this is getting out of scope of this question. You can make a different question on SO on that matter. If my answer solved your initial problem, consider accepting it.

Comment: @ajaysingh please don't ping people so they can help you on other questions like this. It's pretty bad form for Stack.

Comment: @Patrice yes, I should have thoroughly checked documentation before posting. Will not repeat it. Thanks.