# MakeValid not working for a single model object

Tags: python, django, django-views, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to use `MakeValid` to fix (validate) my geometry fields.
I can make it work by getting and updating in single line:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import MakeValid

MyModel.objects.filter(id=<id>).update(polygon=MakeValid('polygon'))
```

but for some cases, I have to update `polygon` of a single model object already instantiated in a function (meaning I have already done `.filter`/`.get`) which gives me the following error:

```
// np is an object of MyModel which has a field 'polygon' which is `MultiPolygon` django model field
np.polygon = MakeValid(np.polygon)
// np.save()
TypeError: Cannot set MyModel SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.MakeValid'>
```

Here, `MakeValid(np.polygon)` doesn't return a `MultiPolygon` object. Instead, it returns a `django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.MakeValid` wrapper.

Can I get a Geometry object from `MakeValid`?

Comment: is `np.polygon` a multipolygon? I remember reading somewhere that makeValid does not support multipolygons

Comment: yes. updated in question as well. And it works for MultiPolygons also. First query works fine.

Comment: FYI, this question is the [subject of a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355484/am-i-doing-something-wrong-or-is-the-user-a-help-vampire).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [stated in the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos?answertab=votes#tab-top) `MakeValid` is a [**database function**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#module-django.db.models.functions), which means that it can be executed only during querying the database.

It is 1-to-1 similar to the `PostGIS` usage of `ST_MakeValid` which cannot be executed outside of a table query (cannot exist autonomously).

When you create the `np` object, and then you try to do:

```
np.polygon = MakeValid(np.polygon)
```

You are essentially trying to apply a database function to an instance of the 'MyModel' class which isn't supposed to work! (as it does not)

---

What you can do:

1. You can create a query to update a specific table row:

   ```
   np = MyModel.objects.filter(id=np.id).update(polygon=MakeValid('polygon'))
   ```

   *Note:*  The object with `id=np.id`'s polygon, will be updated in the
   database permanently with that method.
2. You can utilize the [`GEOSGeometry.buffer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.buffer):

   Using `polygon.buffer(0)` can tidy up most of the polygon irregularities (it can even solve some types of "bowtie"/self-intersecting polygons)

   ```
   np.polygon.valid          # False
   np.polygon.buffer(0)      # Make valid with buffer(0)
   np.polygon.valid          # True
   ```
3. Finally, you can use [`Shapely`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/index.html) and create a shapely polygon for your calculations which you can make valid with the same method as above (both [Shapely's `buffer`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.buffer) and [GeoDjango's `buffer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.buffer) use `GEOS` library):

   ```
   from shapely.geometry import Polygon

   # Initialize the polygon object with one of the following ways:
   np_polygon = Polygon([np.polygon.coords])
   # or
   np_polygon = Polygon(np.polygon.wkt)

   np_polygon.is_valid                 # False
   np_polygon = np_polygon.buffer(0)   # Make valid with buffer(0)
   np_polygon.is_valid                 # True
   ```

Comment: I already have object `np` in my function. Getting it again using `filter` and then updating it will make it make it inefficient, right?

Comment: @ajaysingh Yes it will be a bit inefficient, so you need to decide were to use the `MakeValid` function. Another solution would be to create a `MakeValid` for model objects and not as a database function but that may be overcomplicated.

Comment: Can you give me some guidance on how to create `MakeValid` for model objects?

Comment: @ajaysingh I think I found some solutions without much complication. Have a look at my edited answer!!

Comment: Hey, I tried it today only. It sort of works for me. But it sometimes returns `Polygon` object and sometimes `MultiPolygon` object. Any ideas on that? Also, is there any difference between `MakeValid` and `buffer(0)`?

Comment: @ajaysingh As I write in the answer, `MakeValid` is a database function and `buffer(0)` is an object method. I do not know about the polygon and multi-polygon though, seems strange.

Comment: any useful link to find the difference between `MakeValid` and `buffer(0)`? Also, what's the difference between `buffer(0)` and `buffer(1)`