# Get random point from django PolygonField

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

**TL,DR**; *I want to get a random point from a polygon (potentially) using [ST_GeneratePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html).*

---

**Background**

I'm making a GeoDjango web service and have a collection of UK Postcodes with respective boundaries like so:

```
from django.db import models as dj_models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class Postcode(gis_models.Model):
      pretty_postcode = dj_models.CharField( max_length=8 )
      coords = gis_models.PolygonField( default='POLYGON EMPTY' )
```

I've found a delightful little PostGIS function [ST_GeneratePoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html), which can find me random points in my `coords` region.

**Question**

How can I use this function from within my python django app (or can you suggest a better way?). Ideally ending up with a function like so:

```
from django.contrib.gis import geos
# ... other imports ...

class Postcode(gis_models.Model):
     # ... fields ...

     def get_random_point(self):
         rand_point = # code that executes ST_GeneratePoints
                      # and returns a geos.Point instance
         return rand_point
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a similar question here: [Equivalent of PostGIS ST_MakeValid in Django GEOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Since you essentially want to call a database function, you cannot quite do it as you imagine.
 
What you can do instead is to wrap the `ST_GeneratePoints` as a `GeoFunc`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

class GeneratePoints(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_GeneratePoints'
```

and use it in an [`aggregation/annotation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Value

Postcode.objects.annotate(
    rand_point=GeneratePoints(
        'coords',
        Value(1) # to get only one point
    )
)
```

Another way of doing the same thing is:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc
from django.db.models import F, Value

Postcode.objects.annotate(
    rand_point=GeoFunc(
        F('coords'),
        Value(1),
        function='ST_GeneratePoints',
    )
)
```