# The ST_AddPoint function is implemented in GeoDjango?

Tags: sql, django, gis, geodjango

Actually have a LineStringField on my model, and need actualize this field every 15 seconds, i have a total of 300 points, this represent a problem in the asynchronous performance?.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be implemented at the moment, but you can use GeoFunc to import it on your application. Example of usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos/45633779#45633779

Comment: I dont know the exactly usage and syntax for GeoFunc with ST_AddPoint, help...

Comment: You need to make you question more clear. What do you mean by "actualizing" the LineString? What do you mean by asynchronous performance and how have you implemented async on your project? What have you done so far? Is how to insert a new point in a LineString a problem you cannot solve? Please update the question in order to be answerable. Follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve