# How to make/use a custom database function in Django

Tags: python, django, database, geodjango, django-database-functions

**Prologue:**

This is a question arising often in SO:

- [Equivalent of PostGIS ST_MakeValid in Django GEOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos/)
- [Geodjango: How to Buffer From Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144834/geodjango-how-to-buffer-from-point/45879956#45879956)
- [Get random point from django PolygonField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455081/get-random-point-from-django-polygonfield/46464362#46464362)
- [Django custom for complex Func (sql function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427115/django-custom-for-complex-func-sql-function/46490971#46490971)

and can be applied to the above as well as in the following:

- [Django F expression on datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890131/django-f-expression-on-datetime-objects/43890979#43890979)

I wanted to compose an example on SO Documentation but since it got shut down on August 8, 2017, I will follow the suggestion of [this widely upvoted and discussed meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and write my example as a self-answered post.

Of course, I would be more than happy to see any different approach as well!!

---

**Question:**

Django/GeoDjango has some database functions like [`Lower()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#lower) or [`MakeValid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#makevalid) which can be used like this:

```
Author.objects.create(name='Margaret Smith')
author = Author.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('name')).get()
print(author.name_lower)
```

Is there any way to use and/or create my own custom database function based on existing database functions like:

- [`Position()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_position.asp) (MySQL)
- [`TRIM()`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-trim/) (SQLite)
- [`ST_MakePoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) (PostgreSQL with PostGIS)

How can I apply/use those functions in Django/GeoDjango ORM?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Django provides the [`Func()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression to facilitate the calling of database functions in a queryset:

> `Func()` expressions are the base type of all expressions that involve database functions like **COALESCE** and **LOWER**, or aggregates like **SUM**.

There are 2 options on how to use a database function in Django/GeoDjango ORM:

*For convenience, let us assume that the model is named `MyModel` and that the substring is stored in a variable named `subst`:*

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    the_geom = gis_models.PolygonField()
```

1. **Use [`Func()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)to call the function directly:**

   We will also need the following to make our queries work:

   - [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) to add a field to each entry in our database.
   - [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) which allows [the execution of arithmetic operations on and between model fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django)
   - [`Value()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/expressions.py#L620) which will sanitize any given value ([why is this important?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

   The query:

   ```
   MyModel.objects.aggregate(
       pos=Func(F('name'), Value(subst), function='POSITION')
   )
   ```
2. **Create your own database function extending [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):**

   We can extend `Func` class to create our own database functions:

   ```
   class Position(Func):
       function = 'POSITION'
   ```

   and use it in a query:

   ```
   MyModel.objects.aggregate(pos=Position('name', Value(subst)))
   ```

---

**GeoDjango Appendix:**

In [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/), in order to import a GIS related function (like `PostGIS`'s `Transform` function) the [`Func()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) method must be replaced by [`GeoFunc()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L88), but it is essentially used under the same principles:

```
class Transform(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_Transform'
```

There are more complex cases of `GeoFunc` usage and an interesting use case has emerged here: [How to calculate Frechet Distance in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475858/how-to-calculate-frechet-distance-in-django/56483387#56483387)

---

**Generalize custom database function Appendix:**

In case that you want to create a custom database function (Option 2) and you want to be able to use it with any database without knowing it beforehand, you can use `Func`'s `as_<database-name>` method, *provided that the function you want to use exists in every database*:

```
class Position(Func):
    function = 'POSITION' # MySQL method

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection):
        #SQLite method
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection, function='INSTR')

    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        # PostgreSQL method
        return self.as_sql(compiler, connection, function='STRPOS')
```

Comment: Can you help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56475858/2648947)? I struggle to call `ST_FrechetDistance` function from Django.

Comment: I love this 1 human QA. My only critique is that the GeoDjango Appendix adds nothing but initial confusion. From the beautifully linked source code for `GeoFunc`, it appears there is no difference between `Func` and `GeoFunc`. If that's the case, I think it would improve the answer to remove the GeoDjano Appendix section, since it only leads GeoDjango users (at least me) to believe there is a difference between the two classes. Since that's not the case, why include the appendix?... If I'm misunderstanding the difference between `Func` and `GeoFunc`, please advice. Cheers and thanks!

Comment: @vitale232 Although `Func` and `GeoFunc` seem quite similar, they are different in essence. `Func` cannot handle geo-functions that take as arguments `Points`, `Polygons` etc. (you can test that in a test project if you like). `GeoFunc` handles functions a bit differently and that can be seen here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/858cfd74e958b63e81657e5a9fc5f751c19e8192/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L18 (it is the `GeoFuncMixin` that separates `GeoFunc` from `Func`). Thank you too for appreciating my QA :D

Comment: Thanks, @JohnMoutafis. I got lazy when browsing the source code and failed to make my way to the `GeoFuncMixin` source. That clears things up :)