# Divide multipolygon Area into subarea

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am working on an application, where I have shapefiles (`.shp`). 
I have read those shapes into my PostgreSQL database and I can show those shape coordinates over Google Map.

Now I'm having a use-case, I need to divide these LGA (Local Governance Area) into sub area (like divide an LGA into 10km2 sub-area).

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this using Python/Django/GeoDjango?

Comment: Your question is pretty general (too broad) and that is not acceptable under StackOverflow (or gis.stackexchange for that matter) standards. Have a look here and try to reformat your question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PostgreSQL and PostGIS you can utilize the [`ST_Split`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) and [`ST_Dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) database functions to make one type of polygon split.

1. Use the method from another thread: [How to make/use a custom database function in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689979/how-to-make-use-a-custom-database-function-in-django) (**Disclaimer:** that is a Q&A I wrote) to wrap those database methods for Django use:

   ```
   from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

   class SplitGeom(GeoFunc):
       function='ST_Split'

   class DumpGeom(GeoFunc):
       function='ST_Dump'
   ```
2. We will modify the example provided in ST_Split's documentation, assuming that you have a model named `MyModel` with a polygon field named `lga` and a distinct `pk`.
3. Create a line/multiline (or another Geometry that suits you) to use as "blade" to cut/divide a specific polygon. Let's call that line `blade`:

   ```
   blade = LineString((lon_1, lat_1), (lon_2, lat_2))
   ```
4. Use the wrapped methods with `annotate` to add a field containing the created polygons into a `MyModel` object:

   ```
   MyModel.objects.annotate(
       subareas=DumpGeom(
           SplitGeom('lga', blade)
       ) 
   )
   ```

---

**Important:** This is not THE method, it is a method which can help you grasp the logic of what you can do with GeoDjango.

Another example of how to split polygons into PostgreSQL: http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/6-advanced-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/21-how-to-cut-or-split-a-polygon-using-a-line-with-postgis.html