# Django get coordinate values of PointField

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I want to get `x` and `y` coordinates from the point in the following `queryset`:

```
user = User.objects.values('id', 'email', 'username', 'point').first()
```

These are my `models`:

```
from django.db.models import Model

from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField

class BasePointModel(Model):

    point = PointField(null=True, spatial_index=True, geography=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class User(AbstractUser, BasePointModel, HashableModel):  # type: ignore

    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    is_online = BooleanField(_("Is online"), default=False)
```

I am getting the following result:

```
{'id': 85270,
 'email': 'username_0@email.com',
 'username': 'username_0',
 'point': <Point object at 0x7f8e061cc2b8>}
```

How can I get an `x` and `y`, making a queryset with `values`?

I want to get something like this:

```
{'id': 85270,
 'email': 'username_0@email.com',
 'username': 'username_0',
 'point__x': '-4.266398314110177',
 'point__y': '-39.39432682357033'}
```

I make requests that return 50,000 lines from a database, and I notice that performance is getting worse due to data serialization. I want to minimize serialization by returning `values`.

But the `PointField` always returns an `object`, and I still haven't found a way to serialize it in the best way.

Comment: Show the model/fields for `User` and the class for `Point`.

Comment: @wim, I updated my question.

Comment: Hey @NarnikGamarnik I was making a pass over my answers, did you find any of the answers here helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough luck :/ 
You are setting the points as `geography` and therefore you cannot use a custom [`GeoFunc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689979/how-to-make-use-a-custom-database-function-in-django) in order to apply PostGIS's [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) in an annotation query because they will only work on `geometry` fields.

In order to get the `[lat, long]` values of those points in the `values` results of the query we can annotate the query with the `GeoJSON` representation of the points and get those as values. To do that we will use the [`AsGeoJSON`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#asgeojson) database function:

```
user = User.objects.annotate(
    point_as_json=AsGeoJSON('point')
).values('id', 'email', 'username', 'point_as_json').first()
```

which will give us the following result:

```
{
  'id': 85270,
  'email': 'username_0@email.com',
  'username': 'username_0',
  'point_as_json': {
    'type': 'Point',
    'coordinates': [-4.26639831, -39.39432682]
   }
}
```

---

*As a side note, you can consider augmenting `Django with` django-rest-framework` and use [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis) on top of that which has some very handy tricks on serialization according to [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) standards.*

Answer (score 0):

You could access the `__dict__` method of your object and then directly with your geometry:

```
user = User.objects.values('id', 'email', 'username', 'point').first()
user_dict = user.__dict__
user_dict.update({'point__x':user_dict['point'].x, {'point__y':user_dict['point'].y})
```

Comment: This works perfectly for a single object, and works poorly for a list of 50,000 objects.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik Well, to be fair Django isn't the best tool to handle "big" datasets. For that, you should switch to a direct connection to your database managed through pandas or geopandas.

Comment: Even if we're talking about 100 entries in a list, going through each one to update it is not good practice.

Comment: Fair enough. Though my comprehension of django is that iterating through users will be the bottleneck here, not the dict updating. Best option (with that solution, 'that' being accessing `x` and `y` through `point`) for big datasets might be to create a dataframe of users and walk on with vectorized operations.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get what you need is through a Serializer like the one bellow.

```
class LayerGeometrySerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    """
    GeoFeatureModelSerializer is a subclass of rest_framework.ModelSerializer which will output data in a format that is GeoJSON compatible
    """
    values = LayerValueMinimalSerializer(source='layervalue_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LayerGeometry
        geo_field = 'geom'
        exclude = ('created', 'modified', )
```