# How to calculate Frechet Distance in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

This is basically a question about running custom PostGIS functions inside the Django code. There is a number of related answers on this site, most close to my case is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46689980/2648947). It is suggested to use `Func()` or even `GeoFunc()` classes but there is no example for geospatial functions there. The latter ('GeoFunc') didn't even work for me throwing `st_geofunc does not exist` exception (Django 2.1.5).

The task that I have to complete is to filter `LineStrings` based on their Frechet Distance to the given geometry. Frechet Distance is supposed to be calculated using [`ST_FrechetDistance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FrechetDistance.html) function provided by PostGIS.

In another project based on SQLAlchemy I complete the exact same task with the following function (it is working):

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geography, Geometry
from sqlalchemy import func, cast

def get_matched_segments(wkt: str, freche_threshold: float = 0.002):
    matched_segments = db_session.query(RoadElement).filter(
        func.ST_Dwithin(
            RoadElement.geom,
            cast(wkt, Geography),
            10
        )
    ).filter(
        (func.ST_FrechetDistance(
            cast(RoadElement.geom, Geometry),
            cast(wkt, Geometry),
            0.1
        ) < freche_threshold) |
        # Frechet Distance is sensitive to geometry direction
        (func.ST_FrechetDistance(
            cast(RoadElement.geom, Geometry),
            func.ST_Reverse(cast(wkt, Geometry)),
            0.1
        ) < freche_threshold)
    )
    return matched_segments
```

As I said, the function above is working and I wanted to re-implement it in Django. I had to add additional SRS transformation of geometries because in SQLite-based projects LineStrings were in EPSG:4326 and in Django they are in EPSG:3857 initially. Here is what I came up with:

```py
from django.db.models import Func, Value, Q, QuerySet, F
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry


class HighwayOnlyMotor(models.Model):
    geom = LineStringField(srid=3857)

def get_matched_segments(wkt: str, freche_threshold: float = 0.002) -> QuerySet:
    linestring = GEOSGeometry(wkt, srid=4326)
    transform_ls = linestring.transform(3857, clone=True)
    linestring.reverse()
    frechet_annotation = HighwayOnlyMotor.objects.filter(
        geom__dwithin=(transform_ls, D(m=20))  
    ).annotate(
        fre_forward=Func(
            Func(F('geom'), Value(4326), function='ST_Transform'),
            Value(wkt),
            Value(0.1),
            function='ST_FrechetDistance'
        ),
        fre_backward=Func(
            Func(F('geom'), Value(4326), function='ST_Transform'),
            Value(linestring.wkt),
            Value(0.1),
            function='ST_FrechetDistance'
        )
    )
    matched_segments = frechet_annotation.filter(
        Q(fre_forward__lte=freche_threshold) |
        Q(fre_backward__lte=freche_threshold)
    )
    return matched_segments
```

It doesn't work, as the `frechet_annotation` QuerySet throws an exception:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type double precision to bytea
LINE 1: ...548 55.717805109,36.825235998 55.717761246)', 0.1)::bytea AS...
                                                             ^
```

Seems that I incorrectly defined 'ST_FrechetDistance' calculation. How do I fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

Checked out the SQL that Django composed. It is overall correct but attempts to cast the result of `FrecheDistance` to `bytea` spoils it `ST_FrechetDistance(...)::bytea`. When I manually run the query without `bytea` cast, the SQL works. So the question is how to avoid this cast to `bytea`?

Comment: I would use the shell to try and decompose the problem step by step: first annotate with just the `Func(F('geom'), Value(4326), function='ST_Transform')` to see the output, then annotate with just `Value(wkt)` and check each time if the results are what you expect. Not sure why it needs to cast something to bytea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQLAlchemy example, you are doing something that you didn't do in the GeoDjango one and that is to cast the `WKT` string to `Geometry`.
What happens here essentially is that you are trying to use a `PostGIS` function but instead of a Geometry, you are passing it a string.

Another problem that we would stumble upon after fixing the first one would be the following exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

and that is why we need to create a custom database function based on `GeoFunc`. That poses some problems of its own though and we will need to consider the following:

- Our DB Function will receive 2 Geometries as arguments.

  That is a bit convoluted, but if we look at the code of [`GeoFunc`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L88) we will see that the class inherits a mixin called: [`GeoFuncMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L18) which has the attribute `geom_param_pos = (0,)` and specifies the positions of the function arguments that will be geometries. (Yeaahhh frameworks are fun :P)
- Our function will output a `FloatField`.

Therefore our custom DB Function should look like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc
from django.db.models.fields import FloatField

class FrechetDistance(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_FrechetDistance'
    geom_param_pos = (0, 1,)
    output_field = FloatField()
```

Now we can use this function in our query to calculate the [`ST_FrechetDistance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FrechetDistance.html).
We will also need to address the original issue of passing geometries to the function and not just `WKT` strings:

```
def get_matched_segments(wkt: str, freche_threshold: float = 0.002) -> QuerySet:
    forward_linestring = GEOSGeometry(wkt, srid=4326)
    backward_linestring = GEOSGeometry(wkt, srid=4326)
    backward_linestring.reverse()
    backward_linestring.srid = 4326  # On Django 2.1.5 `srid` is lost after `reverse()`
    transform_ls = linestring.transform(3857, clone=True)

    frechet_annotation = HighwayOnlyMotor.objects.filter(
        geom__dwithin=(transform_ls, D(m=20))  
    ).annotate(
        fre_forward=FrechetDistance(
            Func(F('geom'), Value(4326), function='ST_Transform'),
            Value(forward_linestring),
            Value(0.1)
        ),
        fre_backward=FrechetDistance(
            Func(F('geom'), Value(4326), function='ST_Transform'),
            Value(backward_linestring),
            Value(0.1)
        )
    )
    matched_segments = frechet_annotation.filter(
        Q(fre_forward__lte=freche_threshold) |
        Q(fre_backward__lte=freche_threshold)
    )
    return matched_segments
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about usage of `GeoFunc`! I edited code in your answer - there is a bug of `srid` data being lost after `reverse()` method is called.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious Yes nice catch!

Comment: @SS_Rebelious Actually this is a very nice use case and I have added it to the linked QA (thanks for mentioning it in your question btw).