# run haversine formula on MariaDB server using annotate() in django orm

Tags: django, django-models, mariadb

Hii I trying to run the Haversine formula on the MariaDB base on my model
the model is

```
class MeteorologicalSite(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField("Latitude", max_digits=17, decimal_places=15)
    lon = models.DecimalField("Longitude", max_digits=17, decimal_places=15)  
class Site(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField("Latitude", max_digits=17, decimal_places=15)
    lon = models.DecimalField("Longitude", max_digits=17, decimal_places=15)
```

and this is the Haversine function

```
def Haversine_formula(self, site):
    from django.db.models.functions import Cos, Sin, ASin, Sqrt, Radians
    lat1 = Radians(site.lat)
    lon1 = Radians(site.lon)
    lat2 = Radians(F("lat"))
    lon2 = Radians(F("lon"))
    r = 6372.8
    sql_haversine_formula = 2 * r * ASin( 
        Sqrt(

            Sin((lat1-lat2)/2)**2+
            Cos(lat1)*
            Cos(lat2)*
            Sin((lon1 - lon2)/2)**2
            )
        )
    MeteorologicalSite.objects.filter(radiation=True)\
        .annotate(mycolumn=sql_haversine_formula)
```

and it doesn't run it return `<django.db.models.query.QuerySet object at 0xffff57b99ca0>`
I tried to use lat and lon for 1 and 2 as Decimal directly and it still doesn't work
so I understand that my problem is in the way I use annotate or in me sql_haversine_formula
Does anyone have an idea why this does not work?

sorry for my English

Comment: Try this orm query: MeteorologicalSite.objects.annotate(mycolumn=sql_haversine_formula)

Comment: No still not working

Comment: Try with values: MeteorologicalSite.objects.annotate(mycolumn=sql_haversine_formula).values('mycolumn')

Comment: I print the function and it print   
`raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types: FloatField, IntegerField. You must set output_field.`

Comment: so I tired to print `MeteorologicalSite.objects.filter(radiation=True).annotate(mycolumn=models.Value(sql_haversine_formula, output_field=models.DecimalField()))`
and it print 
`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“Value(12745.6) * ASin(Sqrt(Sin(Radians(Value(1)) - Radians(Value(1)) / Value(2)) ^ Value(2) + Cos(Radians(Value(1))) * Cos(Radians(Value(1))) * Sin(Value(0.0)) ^ Value(2)))” value must be a decimal number.']`

Comment: import field as: from django.db.models import FloatField and then try this query: MeteorologicalSite.objects.filter(radiation=True).annotate(mycolumn=models.Value(sql_haversine_formula, output_field=FloatField()))

Comment: `TypeError: Field 'None' expected a number but got <CombinedExpression: Value(12745.6) * ASin(Sqrt(Sin(Radians(Value(31.004844010347131)) - Radians(F(lat)) / Value(2)) ^ Value(2) + Cos(Radians(Value(31.004844010347131))) * Cos(Radians(F(lat))) * Sin(Radians(Value(34.768962256378373)) - Radians(F(lon)) / Value(2)) ^ Value(2)))>.`

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB support [ST_Distance_Sphere](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance_sphere/) (which is the Haversine formula). (take note of supported versions, its fairly new as of time of this post)

Using [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) you can wrap this up for Django:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Distance_Sphere(Func):
    function = 'ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE'
```

With this you should be able to use it in queries.

Credit: derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689979/how-to-make-use-a-custom-database-function-in-django#46689980)